# How to check whether Oracle instance is started using pfile or spfile?

Tags: database, oracle

IS there a view where i can check whether an instance had been started using a pfile or an spfile?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This shows database was started by `spfile`

```
SQL> show parameter spfile;

NAME    TYPE    VALUE
----    ----   ----------------------------------------------------------
spfile  string /root/apps/oracle/10g/dbs/spfile<DB_NAME>.ora
```

No values returned means that its started by `pfile`.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked the parameter before, although i didnt know what the value meant.

Comment: This won't work for cluster DB (12, 19 version) as spfile is located on ASM disks usually.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DECODE(value, NULL, 'PFILE', 'SPFILE') "Init File Type" 
   FROM sys.v_$parameter WHERE name = 'spfile';
```

Comment: this one does not work when database is not open. ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only

Comment: This won't work for cluster DB (12, 19 version) as spfile is located on ASM disks usually.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sys_context('USERENV','ORACLE_HOME') from dual;
```